# Flash actions get executed over and over

Tags: flash, actionscript-2

My flash actions layer contains the whole source code.
My question is: why does the actions layer get executed with a fresh start (new variables) more then once?

the following code snippet demonstrates what i mean:

```
var notyetexecuted:Boolean=true;
function addNetStream(counter) {
if (notyetexecuted = true) {
    trace(notyetexecuted);

    notyetexecuted=false;
}
}
```

this always returns true which implies that the actions layer is executed again.
coming from java this doesnt make sense for me.

/edit: i forgot to mention that i have an interval function (still boolean should be false and addNetStream should do nothing)

```
function User():Void {
trace("Aktuelle Anzahl User: " + counter);
if (counter > prevcounter) {
    addNetStream(counter);
    counter++;
} else if (counter < prevcounter) {
}
}
myInterval = setInterval(this, "User", 3000);
```

could any1 explain why this is the case and how Flash executes layer?
cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because of your test on this line:

```
if (notyetexecuted = true)
```

It is setting notyetexectuted to true it should be:

```
if (notyetexecuted == true)
```

Note the double ==

Comment: omg i am so dumb... wouldnt happen in eclipse with java ^^" thanks so much

Comment: @Wandang - we all do it buddy, consider using Flash Builder which is built on top of eclipse :D

Comment: Might I throw in FDT - it's also built on top of eclipse, and beats Flash Builder, if you ask me.

Answer (score 1):

Use the equal operator.

```
if (notyetexecuted == true) {
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have several frames in your timeline, Flash will read it and loop. Each time it goes back to the frame containing the actions, they are run again.

Also you can experience double fireing of addedtostage event. Use the folowing code (by default in flashdevelop).

```
public function Main():void 
{
    if (stage) init();
    else addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
}

public function init(e:Event = null):void 
{
    removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
    // entry point
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty clear that you have the answer you need.

But, for what it's worth, this test:

```
if (notyetexecuted == true) {
    // ...
}
```

... can be safely simplified to this:

```
if (notyetexecuted) {
    // ...
}
```

... since notyetexecuted is a Boolean, and can only be **TRUE** or **FALSE**.

Using this style makes your code easier to read, and avoids the **"="** / **"=="** trap.

Good luck!

Comment: ha! i sometimes use that style but am not consistent.i will try to cling to that, thx.